# error in subtract two same size matrix in opencv , maybe error in conversion

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am comparing the difference of two similar grey images in Euclidean distance. The image is in grey format.

```
int dis = 0 ; 
for(int i=0;i<mat1.rows;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<mat1.cols;j++)
{
    cout<< mat1.at<unsigned char>(i,j) <<endl;
    int a = (mat1.at<unsigned char>(i,j) - mat2.at<unsigned char>(i,j));
    dis +=  (a*a);
}

dis = sqrt (dis);
```

But the program gives out a error, it doesn't say what exact the error. But I think the error is due to the conversion - int a = (mat1.at(i,j) - mat2.at(i,j));

I have tried int a = (mat1.at(i,j) - mat2.at(i,j)); still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`mat2[i]` looks weird. what's the purpose of the index there ?

also, you might just use the [builtin norm function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#norm) , which already does what you're trying

Comment: and please add the actual error, even if it was not helpful for you

Comment: copy paste mistake. One question, if I have a Mat, how can I get the sub matrix( a rectangle) of that Max if I have specified the x,y, width,height of that rectangle. In opencv java, I can get sub matrix with submate function, but I don't know how it is like in c++

Comment: Mat roi = img((Rect(x,y,w,h));